# How can I require reviews from a specific group for only the main branch?

Tags: github, branch, pull-request

In Azure Dev Ops, I was able to set it so that PRs into the develop branch just required an approval from anyone, while PRs into the main (production) branch required approval from a specific set of high-level approvers. How can I do the same thing in Github?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding a solution that works, although it's not what I was hoping for.
By adding a `CODEOWNERS` file in the `.github` folder, I was able to specify that our prod approvers group was the owner of all files. Then, in the branch protection settings for the main branch, I checked the box to require an approval from the code owners on any PRs modifying owned files.